# How to set image background in React.js using CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, import, background-image

I'm trying to import an image in CSS to set for the background, and I just can't import it, and the image stored in the public folder.
Anyone have a solution?

This is the code:

```
   background: url("../image.jpg") top left/cover no-repeat;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the image ubication directly doesn't work. In JSX, you should import the image like this:

```
import img from "../../assets/image.jpg";
```

And then set is as backgroundImage:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${img})` }}>example</div>
```

Comment: They did say they couldn't just import it. Wouldn't this be importing? Maybe the original question could be a bit clearer also...

Comment: I understood he couldn't import it by the way he's doing it so I suggested to change the background by using style on the tag in JSX

Answer (score 0):

i think you should remove `../` and just write `background: url("/image.jpg")`